# Magento2 performance killer -factory pattern

Tags: magento2, performance, factory

Magento using factory pattern injecting non-injectable objects such as products,categories.so that it will create new object every time when you use create method on factory object.
Is there any other use case?
I don't think i will add my  customization in factory so that it will call whenever object creation.
Even magento2 core team also not used anywhere.

I think these type of patterns will decrease the magento performance.
Implementing design pattern is fine.but my question is 100% ,atleast 50% we are utilizing that?

Comment: Can you describe in more why it decrease performance and how to you propose to create product model in another case?

Comment: @kandy each entity now depends on another object(factory) to get created.there are multiple chain of calls to create object.entity->entity factory->object manager->developer ,production factory.anyway my question is we are utilizing 100% factory pattern?